# If/else within interpolated function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, ruby-on-rails-4, interpolation

Here is my code that is not working:

```
    $.each( gon.jbuilder, function (counter, lender) { 
      var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
        '<div id="siteNotice">'+
        '</div>'+
        '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">'+ lender.email + '</h1>'+
        '<div id="bodyContent">'+
        '<ul>' +
        if (inventory.hasOwnProperty('description')) {
          $.map( lender.inventories, function (inventory, counter) {
            return '<li>' + inventory.itemlist_id + ': ' + inventory.description + '</li>';
          }).join('') +
        } else {
          $.map( lender.inventories, function (inventory, counter) {
            return '<li>' + inventory.itemlist_id + '</li>';
          }).join('') +
        }
        '</ul>' +
        '</div>'+
        '</div>';
```

The error I'm getting is `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if`. I'm not sure how to write the `if` statement properly to get this to work. basically, I'm creating a series of `contentString` variables, one for each `lender`. Within each `contentString`, `$map` is producing a list of all the child `inventories` for the parent `lender`. Some `inventories` have `descriptions` so, where this is true, I want to print the description as well. But if not, I want to skip it.

**UPDATE NEW CODE**

Thanks for comments! So this is what I have now:

```
    $.each( gon.jbuilder, function (counter, lender) { 
      var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
        '<div id="siteNotice">'+
        '</div>'+
        '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">'+ lender.email + '</h1>'+
        '<div id="bodyContent">'+
        '<ul>' +
        $.map( lender.inventories, function (inventory, counter) {
          if (inventory.description == "") {
            var description = ''
          } else {
            var description = ': ' + inventory.description
          };
          return '<li>' + inventory.itemlist_id + description + '</li>';
        }).join('') +
        '</ul>' +
        '</div>'+
        '</div>';
```

While it's no longer throwing errors, it appears the `if` statement isn't working properly in that even where `inventory.description` is blank, it returns `: null`, when I want it to return nothing at all.

Comment: `if` statements are not expressions.

Comment: so... does that mean it definitely won't work here? what else can i use?

Comment: You can cache the result it in a variable, or use an expression, like a ternary operator.

Comment: *"does that mean it definitely won't work here?"* Yes. *"what else can i use?"* The conditional operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: '<ul>' + if ? thats not right

Comment: @FelixKling just updated my answer, the ternary I also tried, but I think there's something wrong with the way I'm writing my `if/else`. @elclanrs, am trying to variable approach, think it's not working right...

Comment: Well, `null != ""`. So if the value of `inventory.description` can be `null`, you should compare against `null`, not `""`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final answer, thanks for the comments everyone! Heavily drawn from @Felix's comments.

```
$.each( gon.jbuilder, function (counter, lender) { 
  var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
    '<div id="siteNotice">'+
    '</div>'+
    '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">'+ lender.email + '</h1>'+
    '<div id="bodyContent">'+
    '<ul>' +
    $.map( lender.inventories, function (inventory, counter) {
      if (inventory.description == null) {
        var description = ''
      } else {
        var description = ': ' + inventory.description
      };
      return '<li>' + inventory.itemlist_id + description + '</li>';
    }).join('') +
    '</ul>' +
    '</div>'+
    '</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

May this is heplful to you...

```
var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
    '<div id="siteNotice">'+
    '</div>'+
    '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">'+ lender.email + '</h1>'+
    '<div id="bodyContent">'+
    '<ul>' ;
    if (inventory.hasOwnProperty('description')) {
      $.map( lender.inventories, function (inventory, counter) {
        contentString += '<li>' + inventory.itemlist_id + ': ' + inventory.description + '</li>';
      }).join('') ;
    } else {
      $.map( lender.inventories, function (inventory, counter) {
        contentString += '<li>' + inventory.itemlist_id + '</li>';
      }).join('') ;
    }
     contentString + '</ul>' +
    '</div>'+
    '</div>';
```

and at the last return variable contentString

Comment: Hmm just tried, got an error `inventory is not defined`

Comment: then you need that object of inventory...so check your other code...bcoz in your code inventory is not even declared